How can i move specific files from one folder to another, through terminal?
I have a folder with multiple .png and .txt files and I want to make two folders inside the folder I have, so that the files are separated. The .png files will go to a images folder, and the .txt files will go to a labels folder. How can I achieve that through writing commands in terminal (Windows Powershell)?

You can use this :

mkdir labels
mkdir images
move *.txt labels\
move *.png images\


Given this is marked as a Powershell issue, may I suggst to write the full cmdlets and not the aliases? It makes easier to search and minimizes the risk of command confusion

To move files from one folder to the another, it is advised to use mv.
mv [source_path] [destination_path]

Two ways are as follows

Using PowerShell windows command
Move-Item -Path "SourcePath" -Destination "DestinationPath"


In above command SourcePath is the full path to the file you want to move e.g. C:\xyz.png and DestinationPath is the full path to the destination folder where you want to move the file e.g. E:\FolderName

Using linux command as some commands are supported in windows powershell
mv "SourcePath" "DestinationPath"


In above command SourcePath is the full path to the file you want to move and DestinationPath is the full path to the destination folder where you want to move the file.
note: Sometimes double quotes symbols are not required in command and
sometimes they are required.
